# select uniques names when a column is not sooner than a specific date

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to do a raw query here, which I don't know if it's possible or not.

This is the table schema:

Table name: army_attack

Columns:

```
army_name varchar
created_at date
attacked_to varchar
first_attacked_at date
```

I want to retrieve all the armies names whose first attack was at year 1885.

I can simply do:

```
select distinct(army_name) 
from army_attack 
where first_attacked_at between '1885-1-1' and '1885-12-31'
```

but what if that an army also had attacks before 1885? Is there any window function to do that? or anything that might help?

Comment: The instruction is not clear, you want to retrieve all armies whose first attack was in 1885, so any army that has attacked in 1884 should not be listed. Why would you use a window function?

Comment: Exactly! I don't know! I'm not that good in raw queries! thought maybe there's a function for that. probably not then ;-D

Comment: If you provide me with  a well formed example with data, I could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to extract armies that have their first attack before the year 1884

```
SELECT DISTINCT(army_name) from army_attack
WHERE first_attacked_at BETWEEN '1885-1-1' and '1885-12-31' 
and army_name not in 
(select army_name from army_attack where first_attacked_at <='1884')
```